# Bridge networking for 18.04 NetworkManager host and KVM netplan guest

Tags: networking, network-manager, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

The goal is to have the guest on the same network as the host (use the same DHCP server as the host uses).

I got to the point where the host is configured via external DHCP, guest is configured with static IP, they can communicate, host can communicate with the rest of the network but the guest can't.

I'm following the guide about creating a bridge with NetworkManager and using it in KVM (I've also removed all Wi-Fi connections from host and default bridge from KVM):

```
$ nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
$ nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname enp59s0 master br0
$ nmcli con modify br0 bridge.stp no
$ nmcli con up br0
$ nmcli c
NAME                  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE  
br0                   39f90a3b-6090-4b4f-a9c4-76d6b980c8c4  bridge    br0     
bridge-slave-enp59s0  dd58e274-8cfa-4102-b524-fd16d96516b8  ethernet  enp59s0 
docker0               901ac863-2d2b-4351-9b81-fbc2096e398b  bridge    docker0
$ brctl show br0
bridge name  bridge id          STP enabled interfaces
br0          8000.54bf6428c24c  no          enp59s0
```

In `ip a` **br0** gets the IP, **enp59s0** is a slave interface so it shows no IP.

/tmp/br0.xml:

```
<network>
  <name>br0</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0" />
</network>
```

Setting up KVM:

```
$ virsh net-define /tmp/br0.xml
$ virsh net-start br0
$ virsh net-autostart br0
$ virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 br0                  active     yes           yes
```

Guest /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses: [192.168.5.100/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.5.254
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

When the VM is running there is **vnet0**:

```
$ nmcli c
NAME                  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE  
br0                   39f90a3b-6090-4b4f-a9c4-76d6b980c8c4  bridge    br0     
bridge-slave-enp59s0  dd58e274-8cfa-4102-b524-fd16d96516b8  ethernet  enp59s0 
docker0               901ac863-2d2b-4351-9b81-fbc2096e398b  bridge    docker0 
vnet0                 1e6cdf02-8f57-4670-b6a7-b72e15151137  tun       vnet0  
$ brctl show br0
bridge name  bridge id          STP enabled interfaces
br0          8000.54bf6428c24c  no          enp59s0
                                            vnet0
```

In Wireshark on host on **br0** I see all packets that try to go from guest to the network and from the network to the guest (I try to ping/connect to an external server from guest and ping/connect from that external server to the guest). But the connections aren't going through, the guest can't communicate with the rest of the network.

That looks like a host bridge problem. What's wrong with the bridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, needed to allow forwarding in iptables. A script /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/br0.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == br0 ]; then
    case "$2" in
        up)
            /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
            ;;
        down)
            /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

Can also add `virsh net-destroy br0` and `virsh net-start br0` to it to reinit the KVM part.